# How can I set binary weights values (0,1) or (-1,1) to the layer in Keras?

Tags: keras, neural-network, binary, initialization

I would like to ask if I can set the weights initializer in (any) Keras layer to binary values - for example for the weights of simple Dense layer to be 0 and 1 only? This would be helpful for instance in the case of the Conv1D layer to relax the computational time.

Thank you,
J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible by creating a custom initializer:

```py
def binary_weights(shape, dtype=tf.float32):
    """This function generates weights of random 0s and 1s based on the provided shape"""
    # build logits matrix:
    logits = tf.fill((shape[0], 2), 0.5)
    # uniformly pick the class.
    return tf.cast(tf.random.categorical(tf.math.log(logits), shape[1]), dtype=dtype)
```

Then when you specify the layer:

```py
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units, kernel_initializer=binary_weights, input_shape=[num_features,]),
    ...
])
```

To check the generated weights:

```py
print(model.layers[0].get_weights()[0])
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks! Does it set the range [0,1] or 0 and 1 explicitly?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Sorry, I wrote it wrongly, it generate a weights of random zeros and ones.

Comment: I have also added a line for you to check how the weights looks like, you have to provide to variables `units` and `num_features`

Comment: Alright, but the direction is clear, the need is just to initialize the weights right! Anyway, thank you!

Comment: @Yevhenii I have fixed the binary_weights function it should give you the correct binary values between 0 and 1s